# InnoDB table lock for writing but allow reading

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a table `COMMANDS` that users inserts data simultaneously.

After every insert I have to make some (time consuming) calculations and save the results to another table `RESULTS`.

At time same time all users also reads data from `COMMANDS`.

My question is :

After new `$command` insert, I use all rows in that table in my calculations. Every row affects calculation and also may affect previous `$commands`, because of that I want to lock this table for new inserts until current calculations are made and results are saved. But also I dont want to block other users to view current state of `COMMANDS`.

Shortly I want to lock a table for writing without locking for reading.

I'am using InnoDB engine. I read some documents about locking, but i am totally confused.

Shared and exclusive locks, intention locks, gap locks ...

It seems stupid but currently I am using a mechanism like below

```
public function storeNewCommand($command){

    // $busy_flag is an app level global that can be read by all user sessions

    if($busy_flag){
        usleep(10000);
        return $this->storeNewCommand($command);
    } 

    $busy_flag = true; //(lock)

    /*
    ...insert new $command to COMMANDS

    ...do calculations using all comands including last one

    ...store results in RESULTS
    */

    $busy_flag = false; //(unlock)

}
```

I know there must be better and clever solution for this without loops and sleeps. But I dont know which one to use.

Comment: Look out for how to set up a queue, so you can separate the "user input process" from the "saving into DB process" and control how to avoid the insertion of new rows while calculating.

Comment: Thank you @Alfabravo I am using some queue jobs but they work async and it is very important for me the current state of all saved commands after every insert. So I want to block inserts at database level if there is an ongoning calculation.

Comment: For me it's the wrong strategy, to emulate a table-level lock. Regardless of how man users, they all should send their request through the same queue and the same DAO.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do the lengthy stuff in less than `lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults to 50 seconds, then use `BEGIN`...`COMMIT`.  (Personally, I would limit it to more like 2 seconds, not 50.)

Otherwise, devise some other method -- have a table that every *writer* honors that says that you are "busy" in this "critical section".  It probably does not need to be much more than a 1- or 2-column table with a single row.

When grabbing that mutex, be sure to encapsulate the fetch, set, etc, in a transaction and react to failure.  After getting the lock, then proceed to do the slow stuff.  Finally release the lock.

Caveat:  If there is a crash or a software bug, the code to release the lock may never be executed.  So, it would be good to include a timestamp, plus something to notice that the mutex has not been released in a "long" time.  It could them email you about the problem and clear the lock.